# On Loopback, how to perform an Upsert event while using the user_id obtained from access token?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

Suppose that you have two tables: `CARS` and `VOTES`.

Now you want to enable your users to vote in the cars. They can either vote to a new car or change their previous vote, but no user can vote to the same care twice.

```
VOTE-MODEL

car_id

user_id

vote_value
```

How would you setup an Upsert process for that model? Please remember that the Upsert method does not accept remote hooks (before save), which would prevent you from getting the `user_id` from access token.

---

Here are some approaches that I tried, but did not work:

#### ATTEMPT 1

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function (Votes) {
  Votes.observe('before save', function setAutoData(context, next) {
    if (context.instance) {
      if (context.isNewInstance) {
        if (context.options.accessToken) {
          context.instance.user_id = context.options.accessToken.userId;
          Votes.upsertWithWhere({
            where: {
              car_id: context.instance.car_id,
              user_id: context.instance.user_id
            }
          }, context.instance, function (err, cb) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            console.log('cb', cb);
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });
};
```

---

#### ATTEMPT 2

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(Votes) {

  Votes.observe('before save', function setAutoData(context, next) {
    if (context.instance) {
        if(context.isNewInstance) {

          if (context.options.accessToken) {

            context.instance.user_id = context.options.accessToken.userId;

            Votes.find({
              where: {
                car_id: context.instance.car_id,
                user_id: context.instance.user_id
              }
            }, function(err, cb) {
              if (!cb.length) {
                // If it does not find anything, go next, accept post
                next();
              } else {

                // Otherwise update record
                Votes.updateAll({
                  where: {
                    car_id: context.instance.car_id,
                    user_id: context.instance.user_id
                  }
                }, context.instance, function(err, cb) {
                  console.log('cb', cb);
                });

              }
            });

          }

        }
    }

  });

};
```

The issue with both attempts is that it seems that the code does not get executed for the Upsert or Udpate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's named operation hook not remote hook.

BTW your first attempt should work like :

```
module.exports = function (Votes) {
  Votes.observe('before save', function setAutoData(context, next) {
    if (context.instance) {
      if (context.isNewInstance) {
        if (context.options.accessToken) {
          context.instance.user_id = context.options.accessToken.userId;          
        }
        return next();
      }else {
    Votes.count({
      where: {
        car_id: context.instance.car_id,
        user_id: context.instance.user_id,
        vote_value: context.instance.vote_value
      }
    }, function(err, count){
         if(err) return next(err);
             if(count > 0) next(SuitableError);
             next();
           });
      }
    }    
  });
};
```

You just modify the user id and let the operation be completed. No need to do extra update/upsert.

And if this not new instance, check for previous votes with the same criteria, if it is existed, deny it, else allow it.

There is a simple solution too, no need to hooks

```
Votes.vote = function(data, options, cb){
  var userId = options && options.accessToken && options.accessToken.userId;
  if(!userId){
    return cb(UserNotFound); //return error
  }
  Votes.upsertWithWhere({
    car_id: data.car_id,
    user_id: userId
  }, {
       car_id: data.car_id,
       user_id: userId,
       vote_value: data.vote_value
  }, function(err, result){
    if(err) return cb(err);
    cb(null, result);
  });
};

Votes.remoteMethod('vote', {
    accepts: [
      {
        arg: 'data',
        type: 'Object',
        required: true,
        http: {source: 'body'}
      },
      {
        arg: 'options',
        type: 'Object',
        http: "optionsFromRequest"
      }
    ],
    returns: {root: true, type: 'object'},
    http: {verb: 'post', status: 201, path: '/vote'}
  });
```

Comment: Hi Ebrahim, thank you! I believe that your second suggestion is what I need. But how would I implement that?

Comment: Just fyi: Your first code works, but it does not update the votes. In other words, it is important that each POST sent is checked to see if another record already have the same combination of car_id and user_id, and if so, then that record should have the field vote_value updated with the new value. That's why I believe that the upsertWithWhere is what I need.

Comment: @FabioNolasco Hi Fabio. You can use my second code as is. Just `UserNotFound` is not implemented

Comment: I tried, of course. But it does not get executed. I put console.log all over, but it only print before and after that code.

Comment: @FabioNolasco It is the service itself not any hook. You need to define it as a remote method.

Comment: Oh man, that was embarrassing. Of course. Thank you! It worked!

Comment: In case anyone wants to leverage the help @EbrahimPasbani gave, here is the website where I used it: https://github.com/fabionolasco/falsecognates